# Login ajax jsp servlet: Pagina de bienvenida carga en div reservado para msj de error

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

Estoy desarrollando un Login con jsp, servlet y ajax. Cuando pongo mal la clave me muestra bien el mensaje de error, pero cuando ingreso la clave correcta me carga bienvenida.jsp en el div reservado para el mensaje de error.

Código JSP:

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submitLogin').click(function (event) {
                var nombreVar = $('#txtUsuario').val();
                var apellidoVar = $('#txtPassword').val();

                $.post('ServletLoguin', {
                    nombre: nombreVar,
                    apellido: apellidoVar

                }, function (responseText) {

                    $('#texto').html(responseText);

                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <form id="formLogin" >
        <label>ingrese usuario</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtUsuario"><br> <br>
        <label>ingrese clave</label>
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword"><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="submitLogin" value="Iniciar Sesion">
    </form>
    <div id="tabla">
        <p id="texto" style="color:red;"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Código Java Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {       

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String usuario = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String password = request.getParameter("apellido");

    try {
        CallableStatement cl = Conexion.getConexion().prepareCall("{call SGVC_Login(?,?)}");
        cl.setString(1, usuario);
        cl.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs = cl.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {

            HttpSession sesionLoguin = request.getSession();
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("perfil", rs.getString(12));
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("nom", rs.getString(5));
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("apePaterno", rs.getString(3));
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("apeMaterno", rs.getString(4));
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("codUser", rs.getString(1));

            if (sesionLoguin.getAttribute("perfil").equals("TVENTA") || sesionLoguin.getAttribute("perfil").equals("TCOBRANZA")) {

                //request.getRequestDispatcher("principal1.jsp").forward(request, response);
                response.sendRedirect("principal1.jsp");
                //request.getRequestDispatcher("ServletRegistrarVenta.java").forward(request, response);                    

            } else {
                //request.getRequestDispatcher("principal2.jsp").forward(request, response);
                response.sendRedirect("principal2.jsp");
            }

        } else {
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
            out.println("error");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("error " + e);
    }       

}
```

Comment: Chris, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo que puedas leer el articulo de [mcve] y despues [edit] tu pregunta para incluir el código con el cual estas teniendo problemas y de esa manera podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo agregue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver:

1. Haces petición Ajax del servidor
2. El servidor pasa la petición al servlet, que te devuelve un HTML
3. El navegador toma ese HTML y lo muestra dentro del elemento que le indicas.

Al hacer un redirect, *haces un redirect solo de la petición Ajax*. Es decir, el "motor" de Ajax hace la petición, recibe un redirect, va a la URL indicada en el redirect y pasa el HTML recibido al método controlador, que entonces lo introduce dentro del elemento `texto`. La página en sí no se redirecciona, ne primer lugar porque no se está cargando.

Si cargar una página nueva en función del contenido del ajax, tendrás que evaluar la respuesta que te llega en el JS y cargar la página via JS.

Comment: Sí, eso era. Use en el servlet `out.write("principal1");` y `out.write("error");`. Y en jsp `window.location.href = 'principal1.jsp'`. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <body>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#submitLogin').click(function (event) {
                        var nombreVar = $('#txtUsuario').val();
                        var apellidoVar = $('#txtPassword').val();
    
                        $.post('NewServlet', {
                            nombre: nombreVar,
                            apellido: apellidoVar
    
                        }, function (responseText) {                       
                                    $('#texto').html(responseText);
                            }
                                
                                });
                    });
                });
            </script>
    
            <form id="formLogin" >
                <label>ingrese usuario</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtUsuario"><br> <br>
                <label>ingrese clave</label>
                <input type="password" id="txtPassword"><br><br>
                <input type="button" id="submitLogin" value="Iniciar Sesion">
            </form>
            <div id="tabla">
                <p id="texto" style="color:red;"></p>
            </div>
        </body>
```

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String usuario = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String password = request.getParameter("apellido");

        if (usuario.equals("User") && password.equals("User")) {
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
            out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>"
                    + "window.location.href='oto.jsp'</script>");

        } else {
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
            out.println("error");

        }
```

//creo que solucioné el error de redireccionamiento